# .OBJ lacking "apply unit" scale option

Tags: scale, units, obj

I'm working on models that are much smaller than the default cube, which seems to lead to a number of issues (auto-merge kicking in too liberally, color ramp coverage being squished towards the center, etc)

I would think that I could fix this by changing the unit scale, so that the smaller models I'm working on would be treated the same as objects around the default cube size (because they would actually be that size in the file).

The problem is, .OBJ files don't seem to have the same export options as .FBX and .STL files - there's no "apply unit" (FBX) or "scene unit" (STL) option, only a generic scaling option, which I would prefer to keep as whichever number I need it to be to convert between Blender's scale and a game engine's scale.

Am I misunderstanding how I should approach this, or is there some sort of workaround for applying the scene's unit scale for .OBJ exports?